# Cast an object into String runtime Apache Error:

Tags: java, apache, servlets

MY Servlet code:

```
@WebServlet(description = "A simple", urlPatterns = { "/SimpleServlet" })
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter wr = response.getWriter();
        String uname = request.getParameter("unam");
        HttpSession ses = request.getSession(); 

        if (uname != "" && uname != "null") {
            ses.setAttribute("userses", ses);   
        }

        wr.println("In RequestHttp method your name is "+ uname);
        wr.println("In Sesssion method  your name is " + (String)ses.getAttribute("userses"));
    }
}
```

> `Apache Tom Cat 7:0 Error  SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet
>   [org.sathish.brains.SimpleServlet] in context with path
>   [/SimpleServletProject] threw exception java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String  at
>   org.sathish.brains.SimpleServlet.doGet(SimpleServlet.java:37)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: Remove the cast to String. Also, learn the basics of Java.

Comment: i want to convert ses.getAttribute("userses")) to string so I can println if I remove the cast how can i perform this action.

Comment: did you try ```.toString()```?

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for referring me to java basics.

Comment: @JamesKingsbery i got this tackled by just changing the if statement it is nothing to do with the casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
    ses.setAttribute("userses", ses);
```

You're passing your own session as an attribute. I think what you're trying to do is something like

```
    ses.setAttribute("userses", uname);
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting and it is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (uname != "" && uname != "null") {
    ses.setAttribute("userses", ses);   
}
```

Do you really want to add the session to the session? I doubt that, you probably want to set the attribute to `uname`. Pay more attention to your code.

And remove the cast to String, it's unnecessary.

And *seriously* learn the basics of Java before you try to code servlets.

Comment: it worked when i created the session with correct attribute.  Thanks.